# VSCode make launch configuration fail if preLaunchTask fails

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

I have a launch configuration that runs a bat script as a pre launch task. Sometimes, the bat script fails to build my project. However, the debugging task still runs, which is really annoying, and means I have to keep an eagle eye on the output of the terminal before it changes to the debug console.

How can I prevent the launch configuration from continuing if the pre launch task fails?

Comment: Hey there, any news on this? I'm also struggling at the moment with a cmake task

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with a `cmake` task.
I've solved it by changing task's type to `shell` and passing everything else in `command` field.

Now when the task fails with an error (*exit code != 0*), it stops and does not launch the application.

---

launch.json:

```json
{
   ...
   "name": "(gdb) Launch",
   "type": "cppdbg",
   "request": "launch",
   "preLaunchTask": "CMake Build"     // <--- task name
   ...
}
```

---

tasks.json:

```json
...
{
    "label": "CMake Build",
    "command": "/usr/bin/cmake --build /{project_directory}/build --config Debug --target all -j 14 -- ",
    "type": "shell",                // <--- changed this part
    "group": "build"
}
...
```

Cheers